# Difference between <script> tag with type and <script> without type?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I include type=“text/javascript” in my SCRIPT tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985408/should-i-include-type-text-javascript-in-my-script-tags)

I was writing HTML and found that even if the type in the script tag is not set to javascript, the javascript code in the  tag can still be evaluated.

so I was just wondering what the difference is between the script tag with type and one without?

Comment: [Will removing the type from a <script> tag break in any browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485606/will-removing-the-type-from-a-script-tag-break-in-any-browsers)

Comment: Related: [Do I still need to include type=“value” in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364728/do-i-still-need-to-include-type-value-in-html5)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In HTML 4, [the `type` attribute is required](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1). In my experience, all browsers will default to `text/javascript` if it is absent, but that behaviour is not defined anywhere. While you can in theory leave it out and assume it will be interpreted as JavaScript, it's invalid HTML, so why not add it.

In HTML 5, the `type` attribute is optional and [defaults to `text/javascript`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#script):

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME type. The charset parameter must not be specified. The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

Comment: As I see it, this is the only truly correct answer.

Comment: @animuson. since practicality every browser will work without it, **all** the answers are correct!

Comment: @gdoron: No they're not. The OP asked the difference between the two, not if they'll work in browsers. **This** answer explains that. The others I see here are all just poor and lacking information, representing a clear misunderstanding of what the `type` attribute really does.

Comment: @animuson: You're assuming OP meant a difference in specification as opposed to a difference in practice in the real world. Can you point out the part of the question that conclusively shows that your interpretation is correct?

Comment: @amnotiam: Not at all, but at least this answer actually explains a difference in something. The three bottom answers just say "it depends on the browser" which really doesn't mean anything at all, because it's only true by a slight margin. It depends on the browser **if** you're using HTML4 and you don't have a type specified. The point being, it's *required* in HTML4 (only HTML5 defines a default value) so it *shouldn't* ever depend on the browser. Where is that information?

Comment: @animuson: This answer does a very nice job of explaining, but when it says *"that behaviour is not defined anywhere"*, one could say that it is very well defined by the collective behavior of the major implementations. It's not uncommon to rely on that collective behavior above the letter of the specification. I can't say for certain, but I've got a feeling that OP is more interested in practical application than academic correctness. That said, it's good to be thorough, and I think Pekka's answer very much is.

Comment: @amnotiam - It's correct, but not completely thorough. The question is literally about type attribute presence versus absence. For thoroughness, it should cover the case where the type attribute is present but does not point to a JavaScript executable resource. In this case, removing the type attribute would cause the browser to try to execute the resource, with random consequences. Some script libraries exploit the use of such type attribute values to load non-JS resources as data for their use.

Comment: @Alohci: On one hand that's a fair point, but on the other I'd point out that the question was specifically about the impact on JavaScript code. I think that's all Pekka was meaning to cover. It certainly wouldn't hurt though if the answer was expanded to be language agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers default to `text/javascript`, but it's always good to be explicit when setting the type.

Answer (score 2):

**type**

> This attribute identifies the scripting language of code embedded within a script element or referenced via the element’s src attribute. This is specified as a MIME type; examples of supported MIME types include text/javascript, text/ecmascript, application/javascript, and application/ecmascript. **If this attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript.**

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script)

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon the browser.  It's largely historical when browsers used to support VBScript and Javascript (along with others).

Answer (score 0):

Leaving "type" off can cause errors in some browsers.

Comment: Please provide an example. Are you talking about browsers in use today?

Comment: No browsers example, sorry. I am talking about theory and general programming principles - not only for html/scripts/etc. When element is well defined, programs working faster mostly, because interpretation by core code is more simple. Example - you not need of course add to <img..> width and hight, because modern browsers reading it anyway, but for some reasons, is better add this paramater. Back to type=“text/javascript”. Here will be no error I am sure if no type, but browser need one more step for interpret it. In easy words, when no "errors" like this, pages loading faster.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest that the interpretation is simpler when it is not defined, because then the default is simply substituted instead of having to read/interpret the value provided. With images width/height, it's a little different. That's because the browser draws the page as elements arrive. If the image has no width/height, the browser has no idea what its size will be. This means that when the image is done loading, the page needs to be redrawn again. Providing the size avoids this page redraw for each image. Also, it can be done in CSS; it doesn't need to be via the element attributes.