# TypeError: $(...) not a function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, typeerror

I've used jQuery to create a page where users can click on a cell in a table that says, "delete," and it will send an ajax request to delete that entry from a database based on the id of the cell and then it will alter the CSS to hide the cell.

I created a test page while I was creating/tweaking the jQuery code. This page works perfectly. Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  (function( $ ){
$.fn.deleterow = function(event) { 
  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student?')) {
      return false;
  }
  var id = event.target.id;
  $.ajax({
          url: 'delete.php',
          type: 'GET',
          data: 'id=' + id,
      });
  $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
}
})( jQuery );
});
</script>

</head>


<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Cell 2, Row 2</td><td onclick="$(this).deleterow(event);" id="13376">delete</td>
</tr>
</table>

<html>
```

Now I'm working on getting the code to work in the actual page that it's going to be used in. This page has a short form where users can select their name and a date. This form sends an ajax request that returns the results in a div. The data that is returned is a table , and this is where I'm trying to get my function to work. This table has a tablesorter script attached to it and also my function attached to it.

The tablesorter still works fine, but nothing happens when I click the cell with "delete" in it. I used FireBug to look at the issue and it gives me the error, "TypeError: $(...).deleterow is not a function"

Here is the code for the main page where the user submits a form and where the result is loaded in a div:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.tablesorter.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $('#myTable').tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>";
</head>

<body id="my-students">
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<?php include 'nav-tutoring.php'; ?>

<div id="content">
This is where you can view students whom you have assigned to tutoring.
<p>

You may change the way each column is sorted by clicking on the column header. 
<p>
<b>Select your name and the date to view students you have assigned for that day.</b>

<form> My form is here; removed to make post shorter  </form>

<script>
$('#submit').click(function() 
{
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "mystudents.php",
        data: $('#name').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $("#list").empty();
            $('#list').append(data);

        }
    });
                return false;
});
</script>

<div id="list"></div>
```

Here is the code for the page that is inserted into the div underneath the form. This is the page where the tablesorter works, but I cannot get my function to work. I've also made sure that I include these script libraries in the head of the main page where this div is.

```
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.tablesorter.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $('#myTable').tablesorter(); 

(function($) {
$.fn.deleterow = function(event) { 
  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student?')) {
      return false;
  }
  var id = event.target.id;
  $.ajax({
          url: 'delete.php',
          type: 'GET',
          data: 'id=' + id,
      });
  $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
}
})(jQuery);

});
</script>

<table id='myTable' class='tablesorter' border="1">
<thead><tr><th>ID Number</th><th>Last</th><th>First</th><th>Tutoring<br>Assignment</th><th>Assigning Teacher</th><th>Delete?</th></tr></thead><tbody>

<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']. "</td><td>". $row['last']. "</td><td>". $row['first']."</td><td>". $row['assignment']."</td><td>". $row['assignteacher']."</td><td onclick='$(this).deleterow(event);' id='".$row['pk']."'>Delete</td></tr>";

}
?>
</tbody></table>
```

I've done many searches based on the error I'm getting, but I just can't seem to fix the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check in the console if you download jQuery script properly on page load.

Comment: You should add a `type="text/javascript"` attribute to your `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">`

Comment: @Basic: not necessary. According to HTML4 spec, it's required, but [all browsers use a default value of 'text/javascript'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9659074/60590). [In HTML5, it can be omitted, and the standard prescribes a default value of ... 'text/javascript'.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First it makes no sense to include the `$.fn.deleterow = function(event) {` inside the document.ready. You should move it outside of that method.

Personally I would change the code to not rely on the inline event handlers in the table. You are using jQuery, so utilize it. Use event bubling to your advantage.

Add it to the table level and listen for click events on the td's that have ids.

```
$("table tbody").on("click", "td[id]", function(e){
   if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student?')) {
      return false;
  }
  var id = this.id;
  $.ajax({
          url: 'delete.php',
          type: 'GET',
          data: 'id=' + id,
      });
  $(this).parent().css('display', 'none'); 
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R775q/)

Answer (score 0):

Test if jQuery loaded in console (check for `jQuery` variable)...

You should wrap your code this way:

```
(function( $ ){
      $(document).ready(function(){

            $.fn.deleterow = function(event) { 
                  if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this student?')) {
                        return false;
                  }
                  var id = event.target.id;
                  $.ajax({
                        url: 'delete.php',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: 'id=' + id,
                  });
                  $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
            }
      });
})( jQuery );
```

But the most important is check if jQuery are loading correctly and solve it...

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

try rewriting to a usual javascript function

```
function deleterow(id) {...}
```

and in php

```
echo "<tr><td>".$row['id']. "</td><td>". $row['last']. "</td><td>". $row['first']."</td><td>". $row['assignment']."</td><td>". $row['assignteacher']."</td><td onclick='deleterow(".$row['id']. ")' id='".$row['pk']."'>Delete</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's due to this:

```
<td onclick='$(this).deleterow(event);'
```

JavaScript can't see this as a function due to the enclosing ' '.

What I advise doing is this:

```
<td class='deleterow'>
```

then

```
$(body).on('click', '.deleteRow', function(event) {
    $(this).deleterow(event);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off binding those events using jQuery's handers instead of onclick, which is poor practice. Eg:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    $(this).deleterow(e);
});
```