# JavaScript issue with type attribute of <script> element

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I can get the script to run as long as I don't set a type attribute.  However, I cannot get the page to validate for XHTML without a type attribute.  As soon as I set it, my error messages go away, but then the script fails to function.  Below is a snippit of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>John Whiteker's Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css" />

    <script><!-- This is my error saying that I need to set a type attribute -->
    function myFunction()
    {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
    }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this in the latest stable versions of IE, FF, and Chrome. Script works fine and is valid XHTML 1.0 Strict http://validator.w3.org/check

My only guess as to why your script was failing to run was because nothing was calling the function. There's two easy options:

**Option 1**

Call the function with `<body onload="myFunction()">`

Example 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>John Whiteker's Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        <!--

        function myFunction() {
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
        }

        //-->
        //]]>
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">

</body>

</html>
```

**Option 2**

Call the function by adding `window.onload = myFunction();` which would allow you to omit the `<body onload="myFunction()">` part.

Example 2:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>John Whiteker's Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="project.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        <!--

        function myFunction() {
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
        }
        window.onload = myFunction();

        //-->
        //]]>
    </script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Either method will produce valid XHTML 1.0 Strict, and the script will run fine. For more information on `window.onload` VS `<body onload=“” />` , check out this great SO post [window.onload vs <body onload=""/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191157/window-onload-vs-body-onload)


Also, when writing XHTML, it is good practice to include

```
//<![CDATA[
<!--
```

just after your `<script type="text/javascript">` tag, and

```
//-->
//]]>
```

just before your `</script>` tag.

They may not be required for THIS particular project, but a [CDATA section is required if you need your document to parse as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag). Also see [What is CDATA in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092236/what-is-cdata-in-html). Maybe your prof will give you bonus points for including them : )

Cheers,

Lord

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed solution Lord Tubington.  Your recommendation worked flawlessly and allowed me to stay within the parameters specified by my slightly out of date XHTML class and instructor.  :)   You guys are awesome!

Comment: CDATA is never required for a valid XML. CDATA is used if you want to include characters in any text section with special meanings to XML like `<`, `>`, or `&`, without entity escaping them as `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`. Since Javascript code often contains these characters, it's generally a good idea to wrap inline scripts in entity tags, but you can still write a perfectly valid XHTML script without CDATA.

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 is the spec that allows you to omit the `type` attribute and assumes "text/javascript". Every other version of HTML, the `type` attribute is required.

You are using the XHTML Doctype. If you want to use HTML5, include this Doctype at the top instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

From MDN: "If this attribute is absent, the script is treated as JavaScript.", referring to HTML5.

A reference: [Difference between <script> tag with type and <script> without type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659029/difference-between-script-tag-with-type-and-script-without-type)

Comment: Thanks Ian.  I may resort to your solution, but this is for a college assignment.  The instructor wants XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype that includes a javascript element, and the site must pass validation.

Comment: @JohnWhiteker That's fine, I wasn't trying to persuade you to do something. I was just saying - if you don't want to include the `type` attribute, you have to use the HTML5 doctype. You seemed to be asking why it wasn't working, so I explained. You can do whatever you want, but the Doctype is the reason why it's not working without the `type`

Comment: Ian, I do appreciate it.  I just wonder if there's a way to make it function within the restrictions that I'm under.  If I insert the typical javascript type attribute, the page will then validate, but the script fails to run.

Comment: @JohnWhiteker Well I can't help but think that the Javascript you posted isn't *all* of it. The code you have right now should work fine, so you might want to post more to determine what the problem is. That's weird though that it either validates or succeeds, but not both...

Answer (score 2):

Use an HTML5 doctype and don't specify type attributes unless they aren't the default. Also, don't worry so much about validation. It's great for keeping things in order but you [shouldn't let it get in the way of function](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/html-validation-does-it-matter.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
        <title>John Whiteker's Home Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css" />
        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks dtbarne.  I may resort to your solution, but this is for a college assignment.  The instructor wants XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype that includes a javascript element, and the site must pass validation.  It appears that what she is requesting may not be 100% possible.